# Как сделать скриншот рабочего стола на языке C(Си)?

Tags: c

Я только начинаю изучить C(си), до этого я работал в Python и сделать скриншот экрана в Python легко, но как сделать скриншот в C(си) я не особо понимаю. Моя задача состоит в том, чтобы через определенный промежуток времени(например, 20-30 минут) программа делала скриншот рабочего стола и сохраняла его в определенную папку (желательно в формате .png). Может ли мне кто-то помочь с этим, показать и объяснить как это работает. И если это возможно обойтись только стандартной библиотекой языка C(си). Надеюсь я правильно задал вопрос)))

Comment: в случае си это все очень и очень платформеннозависимо. Без знания конкретной ОС, ответить на вопрос сложно.

Comment: ОС - windows, однако конкретной версии нет.

Comment: Быстрее всего вызвать из Си тот ваш скрипт на питоне, который делает скришот.

Comment: @avp Не несите чушь! Снять BitCaps с экрана - нет нечего проще, главное понимать что и как работает.

Comment: @EugeneX, это ваше видение решения задач. В linux проще всего вызвать, например `gnome-screenshot  -f /tmp/scr.tmp`. Если это надо сделать из си -- используйте `system()`. Никто не спорит, можно написать тот же функционал в своей программе, но быстрее от этого прикладная задача не заработает.

Answer (score 0):

Если интересует как это сделать под Windows, и у вас хорошо с английским - то вот полная статья как это правильно делается.

- https://www.apriorit.com/dev-blog/193-multi-monitor-screenshot

Comment: основная проблема заключается в сохранении скриншота в файл .png. Я уже находил подобные статьи, но нигде не написано как его сохранить.

Comment: @BITochek Из коробки C++ не умеет работать с PNG. Для этого надо подключать библиотеку. Для Linux это конечно-же ImageMagick  https://imagemagick.org/Magick++/ Для windows это GDI+ https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdiplus/-gdiplus-converting-a-bmp-image-to-a-png-image-use . Следует понимать что графика в ОS это просто BitsBuffer и ближайший к нему формат это BMP